# XML: 'remove_blank_text' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Tags: python, xml, lxml

Okay, so I'm doing the [basic XML tutorial](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#the-elementtree-class) and am trying to put this code in:

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(remove_blank_text=True)
root = etree.XML("<root>  <a/>   <b>  </b>     </root>", parser)
etree.tostring(root)
```

And what I'm getting is an error pointing to the parser line saying

```
'remove_blank_text' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

I have this sneaking suspicion that lxml is somehow not fully installed or imported or whatever. I have to say my eyes cross as I look at the "Installation" instructions; in very, very plain English, how do I install/reinstall lxml?

(EDIT: Double checking, yes, this:

```
import sys
from lxml import etree
```

Does indeed yield "no module named lxml". Okay, so how do I install lxml?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=install+lxml

Comment: I'm sorry but all of those questions seem to be about Linux or Mac.

Comment: Wait, okay I think I've got it . . . no, I guess I need Python 2.6. Hang on ....

Comment: No. Got all the way up to Python 3.4 but lxml is now saying can't find 3.2 in the registry. A version of lxml that works with 3.2 won't work with 3.4?

Comment: Sorry for not providing details, but this has been asked and answered many times also for Windows: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=install+lxml+windows. If you are unable to make it work, please be specific when describing the problem. What is the operating system? What exactly did you try? Where are you stuck? Also, judging by the title, the question is about something completely different than "How do I install lxml?".

Comment: Sorry, it's just that every time I try to learn programming, I give up in frustration over something like this: Something basic isn't installed. Something won't detect that something else IS installed. I can never seem to get down to actually learning because I hit 17 stupid little roadblocks like this.

Comment: @RaspberryRifleman programming on Windows is a major PITA, that's what it's like in the closed-source-platform world. Btw, if shouldn't blindly add the `except ImportError:` fallback if you know you're using `lxml`-specific features.

Answer (score 0):

Installing lxml on windows is a surprisingly tricky business. I personally wasn't ever able to get it to work until I found this wonderful resource: [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Projects](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml).